# How do I use arguments of a function when using sapply?

Tags: r, parameter-passing, sapply

I have a dataset which I created by column binding using the `cbindX` function from the `gdata` package. This function allows me to bind columns with different numbers of rows. So, `NA`'s are introduced when there are no values in a particular column. Now, I want to calculate the standard deviation for each column. I tried using

```
sapply(dataset,sd)
```

This returns the standard deviation for the column having all rows with values and `NA` for the columns having fewer rows. I tried using the `na.rm` argument with the `sd` function:

```
sapply(dataset,sd(na.rm=T))
```

and got the error message

```
Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

For example:

```
  firstcol <- matrix(c(1:150),ncol=1)
    secondcol <- matrix(c(1:300),ncol=1)
     thirdcol <- matrix(c(1:450),ncol=1)
      fourthcol <- matrix(c(1:600),ncol=1)
        fifthcol <- matrix(c(1:30),ncol=1)
         sixthcol <- matrix(c(1:30),ncol=1)
          seventhcol <- matrix(c(1:30),ncol=1)      


library(gdata)
  allcolscomb <- data.frame(cbindX   (firstcol,secondcol,thirdcol,fourthcol,fifthcol,sixthcol,seventhcol))      

 names(allcolscomb) <- c("1stcol","2ndcol","3rdcol","4thcol","5thcol","6thcol","7thcol")      


        sapply(allcolscomb,sd)

      sapply(allcolscomb,sd(na.rm=T))
```

How can I compute standard deviation using the `sapply` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read `?sapply` manual. Below example of sapply with some extra arguments:

```
sapply(allcolscomb, sd, na.rm=TRUE)
sapply(allcolscomb, function(x) sd(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
sapply(allcolscomb,sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

in the apply family functions the syntax is (data, fun, ...). The three dots are "ellipsis", they are there to host the arguments of the function passed to the apply's function.

Comment: This was already posted in an answer. Rather than posting an identical answer, please consider commenting on and/or upvoting the earlier answer.