# Applying a function to all columns in R

Tags: r, function, smoothing

I want a function to be applied to all columns of a dataframe. This is my function,

```
sma_fn <- function(x,n)
{
  library(TTR)
  y1 = na.omit(x)
  y2 = SMA(y1,n)
  return(y2)
}
```

Now i want to use this function to all columns of a dataframe.

```
df <- sapply(na.df, sma_fn(n=50))
Error in na.omit(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

But i don't know how to give x variable. I want x varaible to take each column as values. 
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried`?apply`? Also, I think you should use `require` when loading a library from a custom f(x)...

Comment: I think you need: `sapply(na.df, sma_fn, n=50)`. [See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30037649/2204410).

Comment: "Error in runSum(x, n) : n = 50 is outside valid range: [1, 0]" It doesnt work.

Comment: I tried apply too., it still shows the  same error : "Error in na.omit(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default "